# Reading paragraph wise in richtextbox in c#

Tags: c#, paragraph

Does any one have any idea on how to read paragraph wise. I tried the line by line but problem is some of my text don't have `enter` after every line and  line by line code consider whole of the  paragraph as one line or it drop half of the text.

```
     stopwatch.Start();

        int i = 0;
        string temp2 = "";
        int linecount = 0;
        MessageBox.Show("the number of line"+ rtb.Lines.Count());
        //rtb.SelectedText.font
        foreach (string line in rtb.Lines)
        {
           // progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            ToolStripProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
           // progressBar1.Maximum = rtb.Lines.Count();
            ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = rtb.Lines.Count();
            //progressBar1.Value = linecount;
            ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = linecount;
            linecount++;
            double check = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
            //if (check%100>98)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("THe time" + check);
            //    //stopwatch.Stop();}
```

or can any one tell me how to put an `enter` or `\n` code after every line if there is none.

My code works fine if there are enter after every line but many of the document just don't have enter after every line.

Comment: Are you sure you mean paragraph and not sentence? It's not for being pedantic, it's because that meaning would change completely the code you should write.

Comment: I don't understand. If there is neither \r nor \n at the end of a line, how __is__ it a line??? Either character works as a seperator of paragraphs and looping over the Lines will give you all the praragraphs there are. - Of course visible lines are quite different when wordwrap is on.

Comment: @gusman its a paragraph  because as we write the in word every enter is consider as a paragraph but if if keep typing than the words will jump to next line without  \n at the end of it but in case of the c# every "enter" or "par" is consider to be line break so if i passes the whole paragraph than it will consider it to be a line worst just drop some part of text ....so any idea what to do ....i was hoping to find a way to either convert  every line in a paragraph  to  line that end with \n  or read paragraph wise...